# Druid parquet poor ingestion performance

Tags: json, apache-spark, hadoop, parquet, druid

Are there any reasons for Druid ingestion to be slow when ingested with parquet data? We have observed that the ingestion speed is atleast 2 times better when JSON data was ingested. In general, which one is better? JSON or Parquet in the context of Druid Hadoop batch ingestion.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're talking about data that is in Parquet/JSON format before ingestion, right? The one answer so far seems to assume that you're talking about data formats after ingestion. But after ingestion the data will be in Druid segment files which are neither Parquet or JSON.

Comment: I am talking about the data before ingestion.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I would never expect JSON to be faster to read and parse than Parquet. Parquet support for Druid comes from a "contrib" extension though. Maybe the performance is the result of the lack of deep integration. I mean the extension may be converting the Parquet data to JSON for all I know :). (I haven't looked at how it works.)

Answer (score 0):

Parquet is optimized for the Write Once Read Many (WORM) paradigm. It’s slow to write, but incredibly fast to read, especially when you’re only accessing a subset of the total columns. As parquet data format is compressed and encoded that's why it slower to write compared to JSON data format.

Here you can compromise with data ingestion performance with parquet format, but for data analysis it is incredibly fast due to its columnar format.